# Junk/spam folder only visible after having opened settings in Mail.app

Tags: macos, mail.app, spam

In the default mail app for some reason my junk folders are only visible after I open the preferences menu. The junk folder then stays visible for as long as the app is running, even after closing the preferences menu.

I am using two exchange accounts and one POP account. I'm running MacOS 10.15.3 (Catalina OS).

So far I have tried removing all email accounts and re-adding them. But this did not fix it.

---

This is what it looks like before I opened mail preferences:

[image: before]

And this after:

[image: after]

This is what my junk mail settings look like:

[image: junk mail settings 1]
[image: junk mail settings 2]

Edit: I now fixed it by replacing the exchange accounts with IMAP accounts, but I am also on 10.15.5 now, so the updates & re-adding the account could have fixed it aswell.

Comment: In preferences > accounts, > mailbox behaviour, what is the junk mailbox set to ?

Comment: Erase junk messages are set to "Never" on all accounts and "Store junk messages on the server" is enabled for all accounts as well (except the pop account, as there is no checkbox for that).

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRSV9.png I meant this @pcpie

Comment: I assume you mean this screen? https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CSpD.png mine looks quite a bit different, but that might be because i'm using an exchange account @ankii